# How do I deactivate a plugin for some roles

Tags: functions

I've tried this for the plugin BP Activity Share but it doesn't seem to work... this is what I have, where am I going wrong?

```
/**disable the BP Activity share for all except admin**/
add_action('admin_init', 'my_filter_the_plugins');    
function my_filter_the_plugins()
{
    global $current_user;
    if (in_array('Participant', 'Subscriber', $current_user->roles)) {
        deactivate_plugins( // deactivate for participant and subscriber
            array(
                '/bp-activity-share/bp-activity-share.php'
            ),
            true, // silent mode (no deactivation hooks fired)
            false // network wide)
       );
    } else { // activate for those than can use it
        activate_plugins(
            array(
                '/bp-activity-share/bp-activity-share.php'
            ),
            '', // redirect url, does not matter (default is '')
            false, // network wise
            true // silent mode (no activation hooks fired)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a basic PHP problem:

```
if (in_array('Participant', 'Subscriber', $current_user->roles)) {
```

That's not how `in_array` works. `in_array` checks if the first bit is in the second bit. So is `Participant` inside `$current_user->roles`.

What you've written however, checks if `Participant` is inside `Subscriber`, then passed an array as the 3rd argument, which is meant to be a `true` or `false` value.

Instead, do 2 `in_array` checks and check either are true, e.g.

```
if ( in_array('example', $current_user->roles) || in_array('example2', $current_user->roles) ) {
```

I would also note that the code you posted should be generating PHP warnings and notices. Turn on `WP_DEBUG` and it should print those out.

### Will This do the trick?

The original answer you've been working off of has major problems, as mentioned by [Mark Kapluns answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/264982/736). Once a plugin is loaded, it's too late, deactivating it will only work for the next page load, and if that page load is an administrator, well, it's going to be a mess.

So instead you have 2 options:

- Do the check inside the plugin at the very top, and return if you don't want to load it. The plugin won't be deactivated, but none of its code will run.
- Don't deactivate the plugin, and instead use roles, capabilities, and filters, to disable or hide the functionality you don't want. This is what most WordPress users do, and will avoid you needing to make the changes every time the plugin updates

In this case, you're lucky, the BP activity share plugin uses hooks to load everything, therefore you should be able to unhook everything

Comment: I would prefer to use role capabilities to disable the functionality that I don't want to give to certain user roles. How can I do this with functions? I can't see where or how else to do this for the BP Activity Share plugin.

Comment: when you unhook the actions, only unhook if the user doesn't have the necessary role/capability

Comment: Thanks again Tom. ok so I've been looking for a way to do this, would I need to use something like remove_action or remove_filter with `if ( in_array('example', $current_user->roles) || in_array('example2', $current_user->roles) ) {`  How would I know what action to remove? Perhaps removing this action `public function bp_activity_share_button_render() {` for the roles I want to hide the share button?

Comment: You'd need to read the plugin, and you'll need to remove all the relevant actions, it won't be just one, but that's outside the scope of this site and in the realm of 3rd party plugin support. Also note that you can use `current_user_can` instead of your `in_array` check

Answer (score 2):

You can not deactivate plugins that way. What your code will actually do (as @tom indicted, right now your check is wrong) is to disable/enable the plugin for the **next request being handled, not the current one**.

Once a PHP file is "required" you can not "un require" it and the only way to remove the functionality is to remove whatever subscriptions it had done to actions and filters.

Probably the only way you might get similar functionality is to disable the plugin and require its main file when the conditions are right.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your feedback. So what I need to do is the reverse of what I've done. Instead of trying to deactivate for selected Roles, I need to activate it for selected roles?

Comment: @Nathan, the only way (as tom's edit mentions) is to disable a specific functionality of the plugin when required. When the role system is fully set up to detect user roles, it might be too late to load additional plugins as the might depend on hook fired earlier during the wordpress initialization sequence..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in_array` function to solve this. A custom function helps you to solve without a usage of a complex conditional check.

The follow small function should use for the check like this:
`if ( _fb_recursive_in_array('Participant', 'Subscriber', $current_user->roles ) ) { ...`

```
/**
 * Recursive search in array.
 *
 * @param string $needle
 * @param array  $haystack
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function _fb_recursive_in_array( $needle, $haystack ) {

    if ( '' === $haystack ) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( ! $haystack ) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    foreach ( $haystack as $stalk ) {
        if ( $needle === $stalk
            || ( is_array( $stalk )
                && _fb_recursive_in_array( $needle, $stalk )
            )
        ) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your explanation and suggestions Tom.

It helped me to get it working The working solution:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_filter_the_plugins');    
function my_filter_the_plugins()
{
    global $current_user;
if ( in_array('participant', $current_user->roles) || in_array('subscriber', 
$current_user->roles) ) {
        deactivate_plugins( // deactivate for participant and subscriber
            array(
                '/bp-activity-share/bp-activity-share.php'
            ),
            true // silent mode (no activation hooks fired)
       );
    } else { // activate for those than can use it
        activate_plugins(
            array(
                '/bp-activity-share/bp-activity-share.php'
            ),
            '', // redirect url, does not matter (default is '')
            false // network wide)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The above function seems to work on my test site but reading the comments and suggestions it seems this is not Really a good 'solution'. I don't know php so I'm just copying other solutions and trying to make it work for what I want to do. Instead of trying to disable the plugin for certain roles, just hiding the "Share" button is all I really need...